# How to allocate different bandwidth for different user in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I have 10 concurrent users, and for 2 concurrent users, I need to assign x bandwidth, for 6 users I need to assign y bandwidth and for remaining 2 I need to assign z bandwidth.

How do I achieve the above scenario?

Can I achieve this by using stepping thread group and how?

if we cannot achieve this by using stepping thread group how will I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this by using **Stepping TG**. JMeter lets you simulate network bandwidth very easily but it is not possible in **Thread level**.

JMeter does give you the option to **throttle outgoing bandwidth** in order to simulate **different network speeds**. The bandwidth can be controlled through these **two properties**:

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

These are for the **HTTP** and **HTTPS** protocols respectively.

**Configuration prerequisite:**

- Ensure you use **HttpClient 3.1** or **HttpClient 4** implementations.
- Configure bandwidth by defining the **2 properties above** in **`<jmeter home>/bin/user.properties`**.

You will find these properties in **`<jmeter home>/bin/jmeter.properties`** location.

The **acronym** **`“cps”`** stands for **"characters per second"**.

**cps values** are calculated with **this formula** :

> > **cps = (target bandwidth in kbps * 1024) / 8**.

For some popular **bandwidth presets** and **more detail** you will find these two blogs [Controlling Bandwidth in JMeter](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks) and [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) really helpful.

If you run your test in the **distributed mode** you can set a **different bandwidth** for each remote engine by specifying your **desired “cps” value** in the **`user.properties`** file.

Comment: :Thanks for the information Adnan ..it is really helpful but ..my question is how do i assign different user on different bandwidth ... for e.g.  i have to run a test for 30 users of which 10 users will be on LAN, 10 users will be on GPRS, 10 users will be on 3g... how do i achieve this...the above solution looks like running all 30 users on either LAN or GPRS or 3G.

Comment: Using distributed mode.Install JMeter instances in 4 machines.Configure them as Master (1) and Slaves (3). Configure the 3 slaves as 3 different load generator for three different bandwidths.

Comment: Results which are going to be collected on master (Controller )machine ...are they going to display me the results separately for 3 slaves ?? or they will be mixed ..i.e i will be unable to identify the responses of the slaves according to their configuration.